# Heap Memory and malloc query

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to get my head around dynamic memory allocation and was hoping someone could explain why the following code executes as it does.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* create_string(void);

int main(){

    char* str1 = NULL;
    char* str2 = NULL;

    str1 = create_string();
    
    str2 = (char*)malloc(11);
    
    str2 = create_string();

    printf("String 1 is: %s", str1);
    
    printf("String 2 is: %s", str2);

    free(str1);

}

char* create_string()
{
    char* stack_str = "TestString";
    char* heap_str = (char*)malloc(strlen(stack_str) + 1);
    strcpy(heap_str, stack_str);
    if(heap_str == NULL)
    {
        printf("Oh no");
        return NULL;
    }

    return heap_str;

}
```

As far as I thought, to allocate memory on the heap, you have to use malloc with a size which allocates a block of memory and then use a function such as strcpy() or memcpy(), as I have done with str2 above (malloc 11 for the size of "TestString" plus one for the null terminator.)

I am just confused why assigning the result of create_string to str1 which is a null pointer which has not been allocated a block of memory produces the same output as str2.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The two lines `str2 = (char*)malloc(11); str2 = create_string();` leak memory.  The memory allocated by the visible `malloc()` is lost when you assign the result of calling `create_string()` over `str2`.

Answer (score 0):

"As far as I thought, to allocate memory on the heap, you have to use malloc with a size which..."
size in malloc() is number of bytes which is unsigned integer. Therefore syntactically `str2 = (char*)malloc(11);` is correct.

Both str1 and str2 are pointing to different memory locations from the heap containing "TestString". This is according to what you have programmed. However
`str2 = (char*)malloc(11);` returns 11 bytes of memory that can store character data type and returns a pointer to this location in heap. There is no issue in this.
However, in your code you have leaked this allocation when you assign create_string() pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have a much better understanding now

Answer (score 0):

It is not wroking exactly as you think.

Firstly, C has constant strings, which will be initialized by double quotes. Those objects when used, actually return a pointer that points to the location of the initialized constant string array.

```c
char * ptr="something"   //"something" return a pointer to the location of the string array 
                         // and is assigned to the ptr.
```

You don't need to allocate memory for constant string as they are managed by compilers. What's happening in the code is `stack_str` locates to this constant string array which is managed by the compiler. So it is always present. You create a memory block and stores the address in `heap_str`, and copies the `stack_str` contents to the dynamically allocated memory, and returns the pointer.
In effect,

```c
 str2 = (char*)malloc(11);
```

is not used for anything and is wasted. Hope you understands.

Edit: In your `create_str()`, you check `heap_str` isn't NULL AFTER `strcpy()`. If the `malloc()` failed for some reason, the program will still crash even if you check for NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have a better understanding now!